# Field image in attachment affect block settings

Tags: views

I created a block in views with field image and title.

Then I created an attachent after the block with title only.

The field image in block is gone after I removed the field image in attachment.

How do I make it override? I can't find the settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

View module provides ability to override changes based on display. Please check steps below:

1. Go to Attachment display.
2. Click on Down arrow, next to Fields, and click on Rearrange. As per shown in screenshot.
   [image]
3. Click on **For** drop down and select "This attachment (override)" and click on **Apply** button. check screenshot below:
   [image: ![enter image description here]

Answer (score 0):

Before removing the field image in attachment Please select "This attachment (override)" on the top select box.Then you can retain field image in block only